# Python : How to plot a raster .tiff image as lines instead of colours on a map?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, basemap

On python 3.8.2, Windows 10.

I'm currently plotting a monthly mean temperature map from a .tif image on a basemap with the gdal package (see code). I'm following a method that I've seen online.

I'd like to add, on top of this mean map, a map of variance that can be seen as some sort of shaded grey lines. Bigger grey lines would indicate higher variance and lower gray lines would indicate smaller variance. Although, perhaps it would be better to, instead of having the strength of the variance show as line size, show the variance as line transparency. I'd be curious to try those out, but I don't even have any idea on how to show a .tif image as lines!

Here is an example of what I have in mind. The areas with no bars basically have little to no variance. 
[image]

Here is the code used for plotting the map (considers the mean data only).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from osgeo import gdal

## Read the data and metadata
ds = gdal.Open(Tiff_path + Tiff_Filename)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]
# get the edge coordinates and add half the resolution
# to go to center coordinates
xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
ymax = gt[3] - yres * 0.5
ds = None

# create a grid of xy coordinates in the original projection
xy_source = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax+xres:xres, ymax+yres:ymin:yres]
xy_source = np.delete(xy_source,(-1),axis=1)

#subtitute -999 to nan
data[data == -999] = np.nan #Set all -999 to nans
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# set Basemap with slightly larger extents
# set resolution at intermediate level "i"
m = Basemap(epsg=3857,
            llcrnrlon=xmin, \
            llcrnrlat=ymin, \
            urcrnrlon=xmax, \
            urcrnrlat=ymax, \
            resolution='i')
m.drawcoastlines(color="gray")
# m.fillcontinents(color='beige')
im1 = m.pcolormesh(xy_source[0,::], xy_source[1,::],data.T,alpha=0.6,cmap="jet",vmin=Min_val,vmax=Max_val,latlon=True)
```

Comment: I think what you want is something like a contour plot overlaid in the image you have. basemap can do that. Also, aren't people told to use cartopy rather than basemap?